# App Engine Backends and Taskqueue URL login Error

Tags: google-app-engine, backend, task-queue

I'm getting this error from a request called from the task queue. It suggests I need to change the `app.yaml` handler but I think I have the correct handler

Here is the error log entry:

```
2011-11-17 13:30:35.849 /tasks/kacher 302 209ms 0kb
0.1.0.1 - - [17/Nov/2011:13:30:35 -0800] "GET /tasks/kacher HTTP/1.1" 302 0 - - "rawload.XXX.appspot.com" ms=209 cpu_ms=0 api_cpu_ms=0 cpm_usd=0.000032 queue_name=default task_name=cf2e2f1d39d108b3972a1da8c6532fea
W2011-11-17 13:30:35.842
Request failed because URL requires user login. For requests invoked within App Engine (offline requests like Task Queue, or webhooks like XMPP and Incoming Mail), the URL must require admin login (or no login).
```

This is the code to call the task:

```
taskqueue.add(url='/tasks/kacher',target='rawload',method='GET')
```

Here is my `app.yaml`, with the task urls as `login:admin` which seems correct (to me):

```
- url: /tasks.*
  script: main.py  
  login: admin   

- url: .*
  script: main.py
  login: required
  secure: always
```

Answer (score 0):

There's a known bug in the dev_appserver with tasks that require admin login sometimes failing like this. Try logging your browser session in as an admin before accessing the URL that enqueues the task, or try uploading your app to production to see if you experience the issue there.

Comment: If I run the url at appid.appspot.com/tasks/kacher it works (but not on the backend)

If I run the url at rawload.appid.appspot.com/tasks/kacher in chrome it gives me a https redirect warning and won't let be proceed. Firefox lets me run that URL and that hits the backend.

But otherwise, yes its in production (@googleplex.com) where I am seeing this URL required error when the cron or task queue trys to run that URL on the backend

Ben